# Should I let MVC handle my favicon request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Should I do this:

```
  // Best practice to avoid MVC handling the favicon request
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

or this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client)] 
public ActionResult Favicon() {     
   var icon = Server.MapPath("~/content/ico/favicon.ico");     
   return File(icon, "image/x-icon"); 
} 

and 

<link rel="shortcut icon" 
   type="image/x-icon" 
   href="@Url.Action("Favicon", "SomeController")" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any reason to use all the controller, action, route, actionResult things here. The first option is simpler.

Comment: 6opuc -Well the reason for using the latter would be that I can specify caching. Is it possible to specify caching using the first method?

Comment: For example: http://www.progtown.com/topic59490-how-to-specify-iis-to-cache-a-site-icon-faviconico-on.html